# Windows Phone ISETool.exe shortcut for currently running application's GUID

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

A week ago I came across an S.O. post (in the comments) where somebody had posted a shortcut for the currently running app's GUID into the [Isolated Storage Explorer Tool (ISETool.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286408%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) command line arguments. The shortcut worked great and was an easy way of using ISETool.exe without having to look-up the app's GUID. The post is eluding me now and I'm hoping someone will be able to re-answer what was in the other post's comments.

For example, using ISETool.exe, you have to add the app's GUID, i.e.,

```
ISETool.exe ts xd 11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555 C:\SomeDirectory
```

Instead of using the actual GUID, the comment noted you could use something along the lines of `localhost` or `http://localhost`, i.e.,

```
ISETool.exe ts xd localhost C:\SomeDirectory
```

I'm aware other tools with similar functionality, i.e., [WP7 Isolated Storage Explorer](http://wp7explorer.codeplex.com) and [ISETools-Batch-script](http://blog.supaywasi.com/2011/08/using-isolated-storage-explorer-tool). I'm looking for the shortcut to use with ISETool.exe, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure it was the *application* that had the shortcut? Going through the reflected source of ISEtool.exe, I can't see anything that would identify the running application.

Furthermore, the Product ID argument is always parsed as a `Guid` and passed to `Device.GetApplication`. I tried passing `Guid.Empty` to `GetApplication` but it throws an exception.

In fact, jumping into `Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity` and `Microsoft.VisualStudio.DeviceConnectivity.Interop` I don't see a managed API that could provide that information at all:

- `Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.RemoteApplication.IsRunning()` throws a `NotImplementedException`
- `Microsoft.VisualStudio.DeviceConnectivity.Interop.ICcConnection3.IsApplicationRunning` (the COM interface) isn't referenced by anything in the `Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity` or `IseTool.exe` assemblies

I do agree that such a shortcut would be useful, so please update if you find something.

Comment: I thought I was sure it was the application that would take the shortcut. I had first used ISETool a week ago and I distinctly recall never using a Guid for the argument and successfully retrieved a copy of the isolated storage. I could be mistaken that it was on S.O. where I found the information.